# What is the openssl equivalent of using java's KeyPairGenerator?

Tags: encryption, public-key-infrastructure, openssl, java, key-generation

I have been using java's KeyPairGenerator in order to generate public/private keys within a program so that I can encrypt and decrypt files(also using java encrypt/decrypt methods). I want to be able to move over to using openssl in order to generate these public private keypairs however I keep getting padding exceptions when I decrypt my files. For example instead of using java's KeyPairGenerator, I try and use openssl to generate keys:

```
openssl rsa -in keypair.pem -outform DEF -pubout -out public.der
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -nocrypt -in keypair.pem -outform DER -out private.der
```

Where I try to use the DER files to encrypt/decrypt my files.

I'm assuming that this means that the format of the keys in my openssl commands do not match up how java's KeyPairGenerator works. Here is a snippet of my key generating code:

```
public void createPublicPrivateKeys() throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    logger.info("Password to encrypt the private key: ");
    String password = in.readLine();
    logger.info("Generating an RSA keypair.");

    // Create an RSA key key pair
    KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
    keyPairGenerator.initialize(4096);
    KeyPair keyPair = keyPairGenerator.genKeyPair();

    logger.info("Done generating the keypair.\n");

    // Write public key out to a file
    String publicKeyFilename = "publicKey.der";
    logger.info("Public key filename: " + publicKeyFilename);

    // Get  encoded form of the public key for future usage -- this is X.509 by default.
    byte[] publicKeyBytes = keyPair.getPublic().getEncoded();

    // Write the encoded public key
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(publicKeyFilename);
    fos.write(publicKeyBytes);
    fos.close();

    String privateKeyFilename = "privateKey.der";
    logger.info("Private key filename: " + privateKeyFilename);

    // Get the encoded form -- PKCS#8 by default.
    byte[] privateKeyBytes = keyPair.getPrivate().getEncoded();

    // Encrypt the password
    byte[] encryptedPrivateKeyBytes = new byte[0];
    try {
        encryptedPrivateKeyBytes = passwordEncrypt(password.toCharArray(), privateKeyBytes);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    fos = new FileOutputStream(privateKeyFilename);
    fos.write(encryptedPrivateKeyBytes);
    fos.close();
}
```

What is the openssl equivalent of using java's KeyPairGenerator? Also note that using outside packages such as bouncy castle is not an option.